# Error 1046 No database selected while creating a table , using python and mysql database

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database

I am trying to create a db with one table, db has been created but the table is not. I am using the database, so I am not sure why table is not showing. If fact, I managed to create the table earlier today with the same code but deleted by mistake and had to rebuild. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from database import cursor 

DB_NAME = 'stations'
TABLES ={}

sql ='''CREATE TABLE INCOMING_ENTRIES(
    ID INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    START_DATE VARCHAR(45),
    START_TIME VARCHAR(45),
    END_DATE VARCHAR(45),
    BEGIN_LOCATION VARCHAR(45),
    END_LOCATION VARCHAR(45),
    HEADCODE VARCHAR(45),
    VEHICLE_MAKEUP VARCHAR(100)
    
)'''
def create_database():
    cursor.execute(sql)
    print("Database {} created!".format(DB_NAME))



def create_tables():
    cursor.execute("USE {}".format(DB_NAME))


    for table_name in TABLES:
        table_description = TABLES[table_name]
        try:
            print("Creating table ({})".format(table_name), end ="")
            cursor.execute(table_description)
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            if err.errno == errorcode.ER_TABLE_EXISTS_ERROR:
                print("Already exists")
            else:
                print(err.msg)        


create_database()
create_tables()
```

And below is the database connection set up:

```
import os
import mysql.connector


DB_USERNAME = os.getenv("DB_USERNAME")
DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD")



db = mysql.connector.connect(

  host="localhost",

  user=DB_USERNAME,

  password=DB_PASSWORD

)

cursor = db.cursor()
```

Comment: Ohh being you like Python .. maybe you should check out Microsoft Workbench .. it makes creating tables like that take seconds, and I think if I understand it correctly, its written in Python for what thats worth to you.  It can parse for you with drag and drop GUI ease.

Comment: The function named `create_database` doesn't create the database, it creates the table. You need to `USE` the database first.

Comment: And `create_tables()` doesn't create anything, since `TABLES` is empty.

Comment: @easleyfixed. Yes,I created the table with Dbeaver but trying to code it in Python.

Comment: @barmar, I am sorry for late reply. My first comment was not saved and I only noticed this now. I managed to solve the issue with your help.